# Как поставить видио и текст на одном уровне?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть видео и текст. Нужно расположить видео и текст параллельно друг к другу по разные стороны. Но когда я ставлю для видео dispay:flex; видео пропадает.

```css
#contact .contact-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  max-width: 35%;
}

.video-container iframe {
  border-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

.contact-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.numbers {
  
}

.numbers h4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <section id=""contact>
 <div class="container">
            <div class="contact-wrapper">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Q8TXgCzxEnw?rel=0"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-title">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2 class="white-text">Heading</h2>
                        <div class="main-line"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="numbers">
                        <div class="number-wrapper">
                            <h4>Номера</h4>
                            <div>Some text Some textSome text Some textSome text Some textSome text Some textSome text Some textSome text Some textSome text Some textSome text Some textSome text Some textSome text Some text</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```